# Sound not working for SCORM object inside Moodle

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-audio, moodle, scorm

Good morning all

Hopefully someone will know the answer to this issue I am having

I am using Moodle

I inserted a SCORM  object inside Moodle.

This SCORM project includes an audio track of text-to-speech for the content pages.  It works perfectly in the preview in browser, however when it's inside Moodle, there is no sound.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Fiddler to trace what is being downloaded to the client. If the mp3, or whatever, is not being downloaded, that is your problem. Also, if it _is_ downloaded to the client, check that the correct mime type is being set on the file.

Comment: any news according to this issue?
My experience:If i upload to server as plain it is works fine(on every device).In moodle its only works on android phone,ios phone but not on tablet.I spend several hours on moodle forum but i haven't found any solution(lot of topic clsoed without solution)

Answer (score 0):

What about server settings for your Moodle server? Does it allow downloading/streaming media files for your course? In many cases, you have to manually add mime types for, e.g. mp4 files.